# nine-patch Image vs regular Bitmap Image

Tags: image, nine-patch

Different between nine-patch Image vs regular Bitmap Image in Android. and where we use nine-patch Image and where we use regular Bitmap Image.

Answer (score 1):

9 patch images allow you to choose the area of the image that can be scaled and the area that should keep unscaled, unlike the regular images that are scaled along height and width in the same way.

For example [this image](https://www.google.es/search?q=9%20patch&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiszoWzt5TZAhXHbRQKHfGdA9MQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=983#imgrc=Bcjnxi7_oOBtEM:), where the corners will not be scaled

It is useful for layouts that can vary greatly in size.

To control scaling in regular images you can use ScaleType property of ImageView

Answer (score 0):

These description from Google search:
What Are 9 Patch Images

https://github.com/chrislondon/9-Patch-Image-for-Websites/wiki/What-Are-9-Patch-Images

Google Slideshow: https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dc7ghz8w_34f8338rcg

very very helpful tool to understand 9 patch image:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#source.type=image&sourceDensity=320&name=logo_cbfea26